# Shopify TaxService delete

Tags: shopify, avalara

Almost all Shopify API resources return an empty object `{}` for the DELETE action, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/taxservice#destroy) the TaxService resource returns the full object:

`{
  "tax_service": {
    "id": 760126902,
    "name": "Avalara",
    "url": "https://tax-api.avalara.com",
    "active": false
  }
}`

This seems to be inconsistent and I wonder if it's a documentation bug.
Unfortunately I can't test this because the API is only available for Shopify Plus.

Does anyone know if the documentation is correct?